# git add --patch in CLion

Tags: git, clion

### **Is there any way to implement the `git add -p` behavior in CLion ?**

I've been using CLion for some time now, but i've always used the git cli for my needs.
One feature that i find really usefull is the interactive staging, which allows you to review your changes before adding them.

I want to use the CLion git integration but it doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible. Pleas vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63201 :

[image]